# Elliptic Regularity for $C^k$-norms

Tags: differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

An elliptic regularity statement taken from Joyce: Compact Manifolds with Special Holonomy (Theorem 1.4.1) reads:

> Suppose $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, $V$ and $W$ are vector bundles over $M$ of the same dimension, and $P$ is a smooth, linear, elliptic differential operator of order $k$ from $V$ to $W$.
>   Let $p>1$ and $l \geq 0$ be an integer.
>
> Suppose that $P(v)=w$ holds weakly, with $v \in L^1_p(V)$ and $w \in L^1(W)$.
>   If $w \in L^p_l(W)$ then $v \in L^p_{k+1}(V)$, and
>   $\left| \left| v \right| \right| _{L^p_{k+l}}
> \leq
> C
> (
> \left| \left| w \right| \right| _{L^p_{l}}
> +
> \left| \left| v \right| \right| _{L^1}
> )
> $
>   for some $C>0$ independent of $v$, $w$.

Question:

> Does this statement hold in the case "$p=\infty$"?
>   I.e., do I have a $C$ such that the following inequality holds?
>   $\left| \left| v \right| \right| _{C^{k+l}}
> \leq
> C
> (
> \left| \left| w \right| \right| _{C^l}
> +
> \left| \left| v \right| \right| _{C^0}
> )
> $.

Comment: The keyword to search for is "Schauder's estimates".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Gilbarg, Trudinger's "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" gives Schauder estimates for Hölder norms with Hölder exponents $\alpha \in (0,1)$. But I am looking for the case $\alpha=0$. Can you elaborate exactly which Schauder estimates will answer my question?

Comment: Well, if that is the state of affairs, then I am afraid that they started using Hölder spaces exactly because the $C^{k+l}$ estimate you are after does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is "No", and a counterexample can be found in Section 2.2 of *Xavier Fernandez-Real, Xavier Ros-Oton: Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE*.
Here is a [direct link](https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf) and an [alternative link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211107134531/https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf).

Edit:
if the operator is of order 2, then one has
$$||u||_{C^1,B_1} \leq ||u||_{C^{1,\alpha},B_1} \leq C(||Pu||_{C^0,B_2}+||u||_{C^0,B_2}),$$
where $B_1$ and $B_2$ denotes the balls of radius 1 and 2 respectively in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
This follows from the $L^p$-theory and the Sobolev embedding theorems.
It is taken from Theorem 1.4.3 in Joyce: Compact Manifolds with Special Holonomy, who wrongly cites that as Thm 1.5.1 in Morrey: Multiple Integrals in the Calculus of Variations. Correct is Thm 5.5.5 therein.